# Break html content into separate higher level html tags and store them in array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve the following.

Assume I have a **string** like this

```
"<h1>My heading</h1> <p><ul><li>Some item</li></ul> Some paragraph text</p> <p>Another paragraph text in <b>bold</b></p>"
```

I need to split this string by higher level tags and put them into array, so for example:

```
[
  "<h1>My heading</h1>",
  "<p><ul><li>Some item</li></ul> Some paragraph text</p>",
  "<p>Another paragraph text in <b>bold</b></p>"
]
```

notice how nested tags are not separated. Also I never know which tags can be on a higher level, so instead of `h1` and `p` in this case, there canbe anything else.

Comment: define *"higher level priority"*. Your filter/sort criteria needs to be far better defined. What is the higher level use case for needing to do this? Please show what you have tried. Right now this question is far too broad

Comment: @charlietfl I tried to make it clear in my examples, any html element that is not nested inside another is higher level one i.e h1 and p tags in the question. So far I just tried regular expressions, but they can only recognize if it is a tag, not if it is a higher level one.

Comment: Put it into another element and loop over children if that's all you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your string into DOM elements, loop and split, and then reconvert to string (not sure if it's the best way, though):

```
var str = "<h1>My heading</h1> <div><ul><li>Some item</li></ul> Some paragraph text</div> <p>Another paragraph text in <b>bold</b></p>";

var arr = [];
var dom = document.createElement('div');

// Convert your string
dom.innerHTML = str;

// Loop through the dom structure and push only direct children into the array
for (var key in dom.childNodes) {
    if (dom.childNodes[key].nodeType !== 3 && dom.childNodes[key].parentElement === dom) {
      arr.push(dom.childNodes[key]);
    }
}

// Traverse the array and re-convert the dom elements into strings
arr = arr.map(function(el){
  var wrap = document.createElement('div');
  wrap.appendChild(el);
  return wrap.innerHTML;
});

console.log(arr);
```

**note:** you're exact example won't work because you can't have an ul element inside a p element in html.

Comment: That ul example is actually an issue as that is how my wysiwyg returns it

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to avoid using jQuery or DOM elements.

```
htmlToPhrases('hello <p>my name is <span>Roman</span></p><span>!</span>');
```

and it would return

```
[
    "hello ",
    "<p>my name is <span>Roman</span></p>",
    "<span>!</span>"
]
```

**Code**

```
function htmlToPhrases(text) {
    let acc = [];
    while (text) {
        if (text[0] !== '<') {
            const nextOpenTag = text.indexOf('<');
            if (nextOpenTag === -1) {
                acc.push(text);
            } else {
                acc.push(text.substr(0, nextOpenTag));
            }
        } else {
            acc.push(_getFirstTag(text));
        }
        text = text.substr(acc[acc.length - 1].length);
    }
    return acc;
}

function _getFirstTag(text, acc = '', level = 0) {
    const afterOpenChar = text.indexOf('<') + 1;
    const nextTag = text[afterOpenChar];

    level += nextTag === '/' ? -1 : 1;

    acc += text.substr(0, afterOpenChar);
    text = text.substr(afterOpenChar);

    if (level === 0) return acc + text.substr(0, text.indexOf('>') + 1);

    return _getFirstTag(text, acc, level);
}
```